# How can you skip images Tesseract?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, tesseract

I have a folder with a bit more than 50k images. 
Here is the code i have written.

```
public static File folder = new File("D:\\image\\");
public static File[] listofFiles = folder.listFiles();
private static int counter;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Tesseract tesseract = new Tesseract();
    try {
        tesseract.setDatapath("C:\\Users\\zirpm\\Documents\\Coden\\Libaries\\Tess4J\\tessdata");
        for (int i = 0; i < listofFiles.length; i++) {
            String text = tesseract.doOCR(new File("D:\\image\\"+listofFiles[i].getName()));
            counter++;
            System.out.println("Image Number: "+counter+"  "+text);
        }


    }catch (TesseractException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("TESSERACT ERROR");
    }

}
```

Somehow it sometimes runs in to the following error:

```
Cannot convert RAW image to Pix with bpp = 64
Please call SetImage before attempting recognition.net.sourceforge.tess4j.TesseractException: java.lang.NullPointerException
at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Unknown Source)
at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Unknown Source)
at com.krissemicolon.Main.main(Main.java:23)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.getOCRText(Unknown Source)
at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Unknown Source)
... 3 more
```

How could you just skip the images that causes that error and moves on to the next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add another try-catch:

```
public static File folder = new File("D:\\image\\");
public static File[] listofFiles = folder.listFiles();
private static int counter;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Tesseract tesseract = new Tesseract();
    try {
        tesseract.setDatapath("C:\\Users\\zirpm\\Documents\\Coden\\Libaries\\Tess4J\\tessdata");
        for (int i = 0; i < listofFiles.length; i++) {
            try{
                String text = tesseract.doOCR(new File("D:\\image\\"+listofFiles[i].getName()));
            }catch(TesseractException e){
                System.out.println("Skipping "+listOfFiles[i].getName());
            }
            counter++;
            System.out.println("Image Number: "+counter+"  "+text);
        }


    }catch (TesseractException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("TESSERACT ERROR");
    }
```

If a `TesseractException` occurs, it will inform you of the error and skip it.

You may also want to remove the outer `try`-`catch`-block.

Answer (score 1):

Just update the try-catch clause location inside the for-loop,
From the [Tesseract.html](http://tess4j.sourceforge.net/docs/docs-1.5/net/sourceforge/tess4j/Tesseract.html) documentation `setDatapath()` method doesn't throw any exception, just the `doOCR()` method

```
       Tesseract tesseract = new Tesseract();
       tesseract.setDatapath("C:\\Users\\zirpm\\Documents\\Coden\\Libaries\\Tess4J\\tessdata");
        for (int i = 0; i < listofFiles.length; i++) {
            try {
                String text = tesseract.doOCR(new File("D:\\image\\" + listofFiles[i].getName()));
                counter++;
                System.out.println("Image Number: " + counter + "  " + text);

            } catch (TesseractException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("TESSERACT ERROR");
            }
        }
```